# Azure RM Subscription - Cost Analysis REST API

Tags: rest, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-billing-api

When we navigate to [**Subscriptions -> Cost Analysis**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/cost-reporting-for-enterprise-preview/) we can see Cost details of resources and also we can apply filter and view our total cost .

Is there any REST API available to get these info ?

I just need **usage price** used by resources with **"xyz" tag** alone in REST API.

I couldn't find documents anywhere till now regarding Cost Analysis .

Comment: [Find-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/find-azurermresource?view=azurermps-5.1.1) is a good cmdlet to know about, but I didn't find any *resources* related to "cost". "Cost Management + Billing" seems more like a service (and a third-party service at that).

Comment: [Azure Billing REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/1ea5b323-54bb-423d-916f-190de96c6a3c) might offer some clues.

Comment: [Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime '2017-01-01' -ReportedEndTime '2017-01-08'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.usageaggregates/get-usageaggregates?view=azurermps-5.1.1) gives me an error, but my provider is in the list of provider namespaces.

Comment: I think Find-AzureRmResource is to just find the launched resources in our subscription . If you know exact API for Cost Analysis you can tell . I have seen Billing docs But couldn't find any doc related to this .

Comment: I don't know the answer, and I don't have time to figure it out. That's why I'm leaving comments. Hopefully, people who are motivated to figure out things will find them a useful, time-saving starting point.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing but can't find it in the rest api documentation.